# How did the Marvel Zombie plague start?

Tags: marvel

I recently read "Marvel Zombies vs. Army of Darkness", and it reveals that the Zombie Plague seen on Earth-2149 started when

> an infected Sentry was teleported to 2149 along with Ash.

How was this character infected, though? If he's Patient Zero, then where did the plague come from originally? **Where did it start?**

I've read almost all of the Zombie-related story arcs (still missing a couple) and have yet to see this question answered.

Comment: Boot strap paradoxes are not uncommon in the Marvel U.

Comment: @cde - not sure I understand. Where does the paradox come in?

Comment: The paradox of the virus having no beginning, it was always fully contained in the time loop. Like sending yourself instructions on how to build a time machine

Comment: @cde - I wasn't aware of a time loop. Was the infected Sentry originally FROM Earth-2149 or something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Marvel Zombies Return wraps up the main plot line of the Marvel Zombies. The Zombies from Earth-2149, created after an infected Sentry appears to start the meta human zombie apocalypse, have traveled into the Earth-Z (Earth-91126) universe. After Earth-Z Sandman uses nanites to destroy all the other zombies, Earth-Z Uatu the watcher sends the last Zombie, Sentry, back into the beginning of Earth-2149, containing the Zombie Apocalypse to those two universes. This is an intentional closed time loop, as there is no way to destroy the virus.

As such, there is no patient zero or actual start of the zombie plague, as depicted, in the entire series. It is a temporal paradox with no beginning or end.

Comment: I'll have to pick up Marvel Zombies Return - I haven't read that one yet.

Answer (score 2):

We don't know.  The zombies were introduced in [*Ultimate Fantastic Four #21*](http://marvel.wikia.com/Ultimate_Fantastic_Four_Vol_1_21) in a 3 issue arc.  The origin of the zombie infection was not revealed there, and the earliest in universe stories we have (*Marvel Zombies vs. Army of Darkness* and *Marvel Zombies: Dead Days*) also do not reveal the ultimate origin of the infection.

Comment: Having personally read the entire series to date, this is the only answer.